# Factorizations in terms of characters

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, finite-groups, permutations

I have asked this in math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698772/factorizations-in-terms-of-characters) but it was barely viewed.

I have seen mention in different places that the number of solutions to the factorization equation $\pi_1\cdots \pi_r=1$ in $S_n$, is given by
$$ \frac{|C_{\lambda_1}|\cdots |C_{\lambda_r}|}{n!}\sum_{\mu\vdash n} \frac{\chi_\mu(\lambda_1)\cdots \chi_\mu(\lambda_r)}{(\chi_\mu(1))^{r-2}},$$ where $\lambda_i$ is the cycle type of $\pi_i$ and $\chi$ are the characters.

Where can I find a nice exposition of this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula is a simple consequence of the fact that for any finite group $G$, the elements $\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{w\in G}\chi(w^{-1})w$ form a set of orthogonal idempotents for the center of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$, where $\chi$ ranges over all irreducible characters of $G$. The proof uses only the orthogonality relations for irreducible characters. See for instance the beginning of Section 3 of http://math.ubbcluj.ro/~olteanu/olteanu-mathematica.pdf.

Comment: ...and I just found out that this is exercise 7.67.b in your book... I hadn't seen it in the main text...

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, most textbooks handle only the case $r=3$, sometimes with proofs which do not obviously generalize to bigger $r$. One source for the general case is [Theorem 2.5.9](https://books.google.de/books?id=VSZIBpYGwSMC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=snippet&q=theorem%202.5.9&f=false) in the text book [Representations of Groups](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521768078) by Lux and Pahlings.

Note that this theorem is not specific to $S_n$, it holds in every finite group, where instead of the cycle types you consider conjugacy classes.

Comment: I am not necessarily interested in $r>3$. I would be happy to learn of a good reference for $r=3$ first.

Comment: The case $r=3$ is for instance in *Representations and characters of finite groups* by Collins, see Chapter 2, Corollary 9.

Comment: Sadly, I have no access to this book by Collins. Maybe some other suggestion will come up. Thanks